# How to model single database items in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

How would I attach custom methods to a Zend_Db_Table_Row object?

For example if I got a selected a user row from the users table and put it in var $myUser how would I be able to implement something like $myUser->getUsername()

Comment: You'll need to create a subclass that implements actions specific for "user" rows and that extends "Zend_Db_Table_Row": http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.extending.row-rowset

Comment: But a select statement would select return a Zend_Db_Table_Row. 
How would I be able to convert this over to the new subclass?

Comment: Please refer to the example in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the default `Zend_Db_Table_Row` and tell the `Zend_Db_Table` instance to use your specific implementation. The following example is taken from the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.extending.row-rowset):

```
class My_Row extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract
{
    // ...
}

$table = new Zend_Db_Table('bug');
$table->setRowClass('My_Row');

// Returns a rowset containing an array of objects of type My_Row.
$where = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('bug_status = ?', 'NEW');
$rowsCustom = $table->fetchAll($where);
```